# Cannot transfer downloaded data from activity to fragment using bundle in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, barcode-scanner

I have been trying to pass some downloaded content from my activity to fragment in vain. I've broken up the steps to see where the error pops up and have made a few conclusions: (i) switching between fragment and activity and vice versa works fine.
(ii) Problem arises only when I enter some data and try to pass it to the fragment from the activity using a bundle.
 Here is my fragment code:
     package com.antojoh.bottomnavig;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;



/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link ShopFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link ShopFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class ShopFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
static ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;


// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public ShopFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment ShopFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static ShopFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    ShopFragment fragment = new ShopFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shop, container, false);

    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);



    CardView cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardView);

    cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), BarcodeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if (bundle != null){
        String value = bundle.getString("coder");
        arrayList.add(value);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }



    return view;

}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Shop Fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
}
```

Here is my Activity Code :

```
package com.antojoh.bottomnavig;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class BarcodeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SurfaceView cameraPreview;
    private EditText editText;
    BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector;
    CameraSource cameraSource;
    final int RequestCameraPermissionID = 1001;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RequestCameraPermissionID: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    try {
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            return;
                        }
                        cameraSource.start(cameraPreview.getHolder());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            break;
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_barcode);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        cameraPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);

        barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
                .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.UPC_A | Barcode.UPC_E | Barcode.EAN_8 | Barcode.EAN_13 | Barcode.CODE_128 | Barcode.CODE_39 | Barcode.CODE_93 | Barcode.ISBN | Barcode.ITF)
                .build();
        cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(640, 480)
                .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                .build();

        cameraPreview.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(BarcodeActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, RequestCameraPermissionID);
                    return;
                }
                try {


                    cameraSource.start(cameraPreview.getHolder());
                }catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
                cameraSource.stop();

            }
        });

        barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {

            }

            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {

                final SparseArray<Barcode> qrcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();
                if (qrcodes.size() != 0){


                            update(qrcodes.valueAt(0).rawValue);

                        }

            }
        });




    }
    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String result="";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection=null;
            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                int data = reader.read();
                while (data != -1){
                    char current = (char) data;
                    result += current;
                    data = reader.read();
                }
                return  result;
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

    }

    public void update(String string) {
        String result = "";
        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        try {
            result = task.execute("https://www.barcodable.com/ean/" + string).get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<title>UPC (.*?)</title>");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(result);
        while (m.find()) {

            if (m.group(1) != null) {

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("coder", m.group(1));

                ShopFragment shopFragment = new ShopFragment();
                shopFragment.setArguments(bundle);


                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.cont, shopFragment).commit();

            }
        }
    }
    public void enter(View view){

       update(editText.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

And the Logcat :

```
08-14 14:46:03.037 5419-5460/com.antojoh.bottomnavig W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://www.barcodable.com/ean/9781614272137
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
        at com.antojoh.bottomnavig.BarcodeActivity$DownloadTask.doInBackground(BarcodeActivity.java:144)
        at com.antojoh.bottomnavig.BarcodeActivity$DownloadTask.doInBackground(BarcodeActivity.java:134)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
08-14 14:46:03.038 5419-5460/com.antojoh.bottomnavig W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
08-14 14:46:03.041 5419-5419/com.antojoh.bottomnavig E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.antojoh.bottomnavig, PID: 5419
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:389)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.lang.CharSequence.length()' on a null object reference
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:995)
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:174)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1006)
        at com.antojoh.bottomnavig.BarcodeActivity.update(BarcodeActivity.java:171)
        at com.antojoh.bottomnavig.BarcodeActivity.enter(BarcodeActivity.java:190)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: From log its clear that its FileNotFoundException

Comment: Hi Darwin. I had cross checked the link from the logs and it works fine! Got me very confused

Comment: try HttpsURLConnection  instead of HttpURLConnection , because the url in log seems https

Comment: Wow that must indeed be it! Let me check and I'll let you know!

Comment: Nope , its not working. I mean the app doesn't crash but the content downloaded from web is "Throttled". Just that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simple. The website did not accept too many requests at a time( which I did). So all i had to do was either switch to another website or wait for a specific time to gain entry for requesting access again! Thanks!